# How to get a two layer sort with a taxonomy term relationship and avoid duplicates in a user view

Tags: 7, views

I have a user view, that needs to list users, sorted by the weight of an taxonomy term associated with the user via an entity reference field and added as a relationship in the view.  Once I've sorted by term weight, I next need to sort by the family name field of the user.  As soon as I add the second sort I start getting duplicates.  How can I accomplish the sort I need without the duplicates?

Turning on aggregation and grouping by the sort AND adding distinct to the query settings works in my simplified version of the view, but once I add in the other things the view won't load with aggregation on.

**Update:** I thought I had it simplified as far as it could go, but it turns out the relationship has nothing to do with it.  I get duplicates just be adding a sort of family name.  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the 'family name field' is?

Comment: Sure.  It is a translatable text field, that holds the user's Family Name.  I wonder if I'm getting duplicates because their name exists in two languages...

Comment: That could certainly be possible - could you try adding a filter to restrict to one language?

Comment: You a hero! Adding a filter that familyname language had to be English did it for me.  Would you please write it up as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ratface and so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a filter that restricts family name to one language.

<sup>Credit: @[ratface](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206888/how-to-get-a-two-layer-sort-with-a-taxonomy-term-relationship-and-avoid-duplicat#comment-251978),</sup> <sup>answering this Q as per [What should I do when an answer has been added as comment?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/848/what-should-i-do-when-an-answer-has-been-added-as-comment)</sup>